# Using SmartExtension API to control Sony Car HiFi Device

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I recently got a Sony MEX BT4100U car radio with support for the "App Remote"-feature. Sony offers a apps which bring "Smart Extras" to this radio. It's possible to hear tweets from twitter or the contents of an RSS feed through this addons without touching the phone.

I am wondering if it's possible to use the Sony AddOn SDK / Smart Extension API to extend the functionality by myself. The list of target devices in the Sony-SDK does not include any Sony Automotive devices but a set of smartwatches and headsets.

Does anyone has experience with this topic and is able to point out if it's generally possible to extend the radio functionality via the mentioned SDK or do I have to deal with some closed plugin-architecture?

My goal is to write an extension which will warn me of speed cameras via text to speech, as soon as a new speed camera is on my route. The warning should be displayed on the car radio, regardless of the configured audio source.

Does anyone have:

- the information if this SDK is the right choice to control this type of Sony device
- if it's possible to reach my described goal with it or if there are any impossibilities
- other related information or special requirements for controlling Sony automotive devices via bluetooth

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Sony Add-on SDK does not support any car stereos at this time and I am not aware of any public APIs available for that device.  If I hear anything in the future I will follow up here.